# Combine duplicates and average values

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of objects that may or may not contain objects with the same property. In cases where duplicates exist (eg. objects with the same property value), I'd like to combine them by averaging their values.

For example (the actual objects can have more than the 3 properties):

```
var myList = List<Attribute>(){
    new Attribute(){Id = "Score", Label = "Score", Rating = 4.5},
    new Attribute(){Id = "Price", Label = "Retail Price", Rating = 14.99},
    new Attribute(){Id = "Score", Label = "Score", Rating = 3.5},
    new Attribute(){Id = "Value", Label = "Overall Value", Rating = 5}
}
```

I'd like to combine the two Attributes with the property Id = "Score" and take the average of the two Ratings to get something like:

```
var myList = List<Attribute>(){
    new Attribute(){Id = "Score", Label = "Score", Rating = 4.0},
    new Attribute(){Id = "Price", Label = "Retail Price", Rating = 14.99},
    new Attribute(){Id = "Value", Label = "Overall Value", Rating = 5}
}
```

I believe I need to use `GroupBy`, `Select`, and `Average` something like this pseudocode `myList.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x=> new{ x.Id, x.Label, x.Average(x=>x.Rating)} )`

Can someone point me in the right direction, please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what about `Label` property, will it be the same always? Nevertheles, it should look like:

```
var output = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Id,
                            (key, values) => new Attribute() 
                            {
                               Id = key,
                               Label = values.First().Label,
                               Rating = values.Average(v => v.Rating)
                            })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: The labels all equal "Quality" because I did a sloppy job writing up pseudocode with copy/paste. So sorry about that.

Comment: @CacaMilis, then, how do you want to group labels?

Comment: @CacaMilis, with your edit, I believe `First` will be enough for getting label for group.

Comment: The labels for each Id are the same. They are just human readable/formatted strings that are used by the view. I just need to make sure they aren't lost. The above code works great. Thank you very much for the assist.